# Replacing Part of Webelement with string in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, qwebelement

I want to replace a part of webelement with another String
For example **Webelement span[text()='%s']**, I want to replace %s with a string like **"Rajesh"**.
So how can i do it?

Answer (score -1):

In Java, Use this:

```
  String value = "Rajesh";
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("span[text()='%s']"));
  WebElement newElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("span[text()='"+value+"']"));
```

From method, as you mentioned int he comment, we can create like this:

```
private static void locatorwithvalue(WebElement element, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        String element1 = element.toString().replace(oldValue,newValue);
        WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(element1));
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to create a method which take webelement and string as argument and reaplace %s in webelement with the string and return a new web element with replaced string

Comment: Can you provide your method code here?

Comment: i cannot provide that but here is an example

public void RepLaceString(Webelement ele, String str)
{
 // inside this method the %s in Webelemt is replaced by the string in argument and return Webelement will be replaced with String str in place of %S;
}

Comment: Sorry if i cant explain it nicely

Comment: public webelement RepLaceString(Webelement ele, String str)*

Comment: I have updated the answer. Convert the element to string first. Then use replace all for the value, and then use this new string for creating updated element

Comment: @Snk2611uk Can you accept this answer if it solves your problem?